# Make register manual laravel with user picture error in file form

Tags: laravel

Error when I submit form to insert to database. The problem is why picture does not exist?

> Method Illuminate\Http\Request::picture does not exist.

This is my Controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\User;
use File;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function registeract(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'          => 'required|alpha',
            'email'         => 'required|email',
            'level'         => 'required|alpha',
            'picture'       => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:1048',
            'password'      => 'required'
        ]);

        // Menyiapkan data gambar yg diupload ke variable $file
        $picture = $request->picture('picture');
        $file_name = time()."_".$picture->getClientOriginalName();

        // Isi dengan nama folder tempat kemana file diupload
        $upload_directory = 'p_users';
        $picture->move($upload_directory, $file_name);

        User::create([
            'name'              => $request->name,
            'email'             => $request->email,
            'level'             => $request->level,
            'picture'           => $file_name,
            'password'          => bcrypt($request->password),
            'remember_token'    => Str::random(60)
        ]);

        return redirect('/ec-admin/users')->with('usrsinsertno', 'Data Inserted Successfully!');
    }
}
```

I don't know therefore can use as Model but I see on youtube that there some people use as model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'level', 'picture', 'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picture method doesn't exist on Laravel's request class.

You need to use `$picture = $request->file('picture');`

Answer (score 0):

Any methods that appear in your head cannot be used.

There is no method like `picture` in Laravel, as @amirrezam75 mentioned.

Firstly, you need to check if the file exists. You can then save the file and its name.

Try below code:

```
if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
    $picture = $request->picture('picture');
    $file_name = time()."_".$picture->getClientOriginalName();
}else{
    $file_name = null;
}
```